# What is the right way of annotating constructor of abstract class to make Mypy happy?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, python-dataclasses

I have an abstract base class `BsaeFoo` that my dataclasses such as `ChildFoo` is inheriting from.

```py
from abc import ABCMeta
from typing import Dict, Any, TypeVar, Type
from dataclasses import dataclass

Foo = TypeVar("Foo", bound="BaseFoo")


class BaseFoo(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls: Type[Foo], data: Dict[str, Any]) -> Foo:
        init_data = {key: data.get(key, None) for key in cls.__annotations__}
        return cls(**init_data)


@dataclass
class ChildFoo(BaseFoo):
    x: int
    y: int
```

Running Mypy gives me

```
main.py:12: error: Too many arguments for "BaseFoo"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

`from_dict` would be an alternative constructor of the child dataclasses. It reads the input dict based on the `cls.__annotations__` attribute, so it won't raise in the child classes. As for `BaseFoo` itself, it does not make sense to check initialization since it is an abstract class.

How do I make `BaseFoo.from_dict` pass Mypy without using `# type: ignore` ?

Comment: What version of mypy are you running? This validates just fine for me with mypy `0.942`

Comment: I find it odd that a version of `mypy` *does* accept this. It seems to be making too many assumptions about how any child class would be defined. What if `ChildFoo` weren't defined using `dataclass`, and explicitly defined an `__init__` method that had required arguments? `cls(**init_data)` would be a call with no arguments.

Comment: (For that matter, it assumes that `cls` will *have* annotations, something not required by `BaseFoo` itself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add explicit definition of `__init__` in `BaseFoo`

```py
class BaseFoo(ABC):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls: type[Foo], data: Dict[str, Any]) -> Foo:
        init_data = {key: data.get(key, None) for key in cls.__annotations__}
        return cls(**init_data)
```